# How to solve runtime error in finding the largest number among n numbers

Tags: c++

As I'm new to c++ I get runtime error for first example(I mean I tested my program with 5 examples it actually happens automatically by a site for testing) of my program I know that's because of exceeding time for running it but I dunno how to fix this.
My program get n numbers from user and finds the largest one and prints it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<curses.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int *p = new int(n);

    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        cin >> *(p+i);
    }

    int largest = *p;

     for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
         if(largest < *(p+i))
             largest = *(p+i);
      } 

     cout << largest;
     return(0);
 }
```

Comment: `int *p=new int(n);` -- This does not do what you think it does.  Look more closely at it.

Comment: Unless you're willing to find the pointer and memory address reference, etc. fix the lines "int *p"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *p=new int(n);`

The line above allocates just a single `int`, and sets the value to `n`.  It does not allocate an array of `n` integers.

That line should be:

`int *p=new int[n];`

And then `delete [] p;` to deallocate the memory.

---

But better yet:

```
#include <vector>
//...
std::vector<int> p(n);
```

is the preferred way to utilize dynamic arrays in C++.

Then the input loop would simply be:

```
for(int i=0;i<n; i++)
{
    cin >> p[i];
}
```

That same input loop could have been used if you had used the pointer version.

---

Then you have this error:

`for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)`

Arrays (and vectors) are indexed starting from `0` with the upper index at `n-1`, where `n` is the total number of elements.  That loop has an off-by-one error, where it exceeds the upper index on the last loop.

Basically any loop that uses `<=` as the limiting condition is suspect.  That line should be:

`for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

(Note that I changed the code above to fix this error).

---

However ultimately, that entire loop to figure out the largest can be accomplished with a single line of code using the [std::max_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) function:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int largest = *std::max_element(p, p + n);
```

and if using `std::vector`:

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
int largest = *std::max_element(p.begin(), p.begin() + n);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on suggested changes in this slightly modified version:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned n;             // don't allow a negative amount of numbers
    if(std::cin >> n) {     // check that "cin >> n" succeeds
        int* p=new int[n];  // allocate an array of n ints instead of one int with value n

        for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) {               // corrected bounds [0,n) 
            if(not (std::cin >> p[i])) return 1; // check that "cin >> ..." succeeds
        }

        int largest = p[0];

        for(int i=1; i < n; ++i) { // corrected bounds again, [1,n)
            if(largest < p[i])
                largest = p[i];
        }

        delete[] p; // free the memory when done

        std::cout << largest << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note that using `*(p + i)` does the same as using `p[i]`. The latter is often preferred.

This would work if all `cin >> ...` works, but shows some of the hazards when using raw pointers. If extracting the `n` ints failes, the program will `return 1` and leak the memory allocated with `new int[n]`.

A rewrite using a smart pointer (`std::unique_ptr<int[]>`) that automatically deallocates the memory when it goes out of scope:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>    // std::unique_ptr

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    if(std::cin >> n) {
        std::unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[n]);

        for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) { // corrected bounds [0,n) 
            if(not (std::cin >> p[i])) return 1;             // will not leak "p"
        }

        int largest = p[0];

        for(int i=1; i < n; ++i) {
            if(largest < p[i])
                largest = p[i];
        }

        std::cout << largest << '\n';
    } // p is automatically delete[]ed here
}
```

However, it's often convenient to store an array and its size together and to do this, you could use a `std::vector<int>` instead. It comes with a lot of convenient member functions, like, `size()` - and also `begin()` and `end()` which lets you use it in range-based for loops.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>    // std::vector

int main()
{
    unsigned n;
    if(std::cin >> n) {
        std::vector<int> p(n); // a vector of n ints

        // a range-based for loop, "elem" becomes a refrence to each element in "p":
        for(int& elem : p) {
            if(not (std::cin >> elem)) return 1;
        }

        int largest = p[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < p.size(); ++i) { // using the size() member function
            if(largest < p[i])
                largest = p[i];
        }

        std::cout << largest << '\n';
    }
}
```

That said, you don't need to store *any* number in an array to figure out what the largest number is. Instead, just compare the input with the currently largest number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>   // std::numeric_limits

int main()
{
    unsigned n;

    if(std::cin >> n) {
        // initialize with the smallest possible int:
        int largest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();

        while(n--) {
            int tmp;
            if(not (std::cin >> tmp)) return 1;

            if(largest < tmp)
                largest = tmp;
        }
        std::cout << largest << '\n';
    }
}
```